# Как откатиться к определенной версии файла, не затронув изменения в других

Tags: git, gitlab, git-reset, git-revert

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить вот такую проблему:
*есть проект в локальном репозитории GIT (работаю в ОС Windows с консолью GitBash), который содержит несколько файлов (1, 2, 3). Файлы периодически меняются в разный временной промежуток (н-р, 1-в понедельник, 2- во вторник и т.д.). Все изменения зеркалятся в удаленный репозиторий на сервер Gitlab. Через некоторое время я понимаю, что изменения 1-го файла мне не нужны и я хочу вернутся к его определенной версии.*
Мой вопрос: **возможно ли (*если да - то как*) вернутся к конкретной версии файла, но чтобы при этом остались измения в других файлах?**
Или такой вариант возможен только если создавать отдельную ветку?

Comment: самый обычный checkout. только файл указываете: `$ git checkout указатель -- путь/к/файлу`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin подскажите, пожалуйста, что дальше? Выполнила команду _git checkout 3ba0f12_ Я теперь могу делать изменения в файле и записывать их в новую ветку? А как мне отправить эти изменения (или текущее состояние после сheckout) в удаленный репозиторий?. Вот что у меня вышло:делала запрос отсюда: мой логин MINGW32 /M/Gitlab/Project (master)
$ git checkout 3ba0f12
Note: checking out '3ba0f12'.
HEAD is now at 3ba0f12... Тест
после этого оказалась здесь: yмой логин MINGW32 /M/Gitlab/Project ((3ba0f12...)) А вот что делать дальше я не знаю. Как отправить это состояние на сервер?

Comment: Вернутся к определенной версии файла в локальном репозитории у меня получилось. А вот как теперь текущее состояние отправить в удаленный репозиторий - не знаю.Команда _git push -f_ не помогает, пишет, что "failed to push some refs to адрес". Хотя права в проекте "Владелец"

Comment: вы переключили всю рабочую копию на указанный коммит. переключитесь назад, на нужную вам ветку/метку: `$ git checkout ветка/метка`

Comment: Я это поняла, поэтому переделала вот так: логин MINGW32 /M/Gitlab/Project (master)
$ git reset --hard HEAD@{22}
HEAD is now at 3ba0f12 Тест

логин MINGW32 /M/Gitlab/Project (master)
$ git checkout HEAD Test_sql.sql  На локальном компьютере теперь нужный файл. А как мне это состояние теперь запушить на сервер? В ветку мастер или можно в другую (на сервере у меня пока только одна ветка). При выполнении push (push -f и push --force) - выдает ошибку.Требует сначала сделать pull

Answer (score 1):

команда `checkout` распаковывает из указанной ревизии **всё** содержимое рабочего каталога:

```
$ git checkout указатель-или-хэш-коммита
```

а если указать какие-нибудь файлы/каталоги, то из указанной ревизии будут распакованы **только** перечисленные файлы/каталоги. чтобы исключить неоднозначности (когда имя файла/каталога может совпадать с именем какого-нибудь из указателей — ветки или метки), лучше добавить `--` перед списком имён:

```
$ git checkout 12345abc -- файл1 файл2 ...
```

---

состояние рабочей копии сразу после указанной команды:

```
$ git status
On branch ветка
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/ветка'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   файл1
    modified:   файл2
```

т.е., если требуется, то можно сразу выполнять команду `commit` — «изменения» уже находятся в индексе.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Всё получилось!!!

Answer (score 1):

Получить определеную ревизию (версию) для одного файла

```
git checkout  <hash> -- /path/to/your/file.ext
--
git checkout v1.2.3 -- file         # из тега v1.2.3
git checkout stable -- file         # из ветки stable
git checkout origin/master -- file  # upstream master
git checkout HEAD -- file           # версия из самого последнего коммита
git checkout HEAD^ -- file          # версия "перед" последним коммитом
```

Дальше работаете как обычно: git add, git commit, git push.

> **И особое замечание**.
>   У вас есть доступ к Gitlab. Если нет особых требований к истории, то просто  скопируйте содержание файла (нужной вам версии) и замените его на вашей рабочей станции. Сохраните и опубликуйте. Не забывайте, что это тоже возможно, это просто файлы.

Ссылки:

- [ответ 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692246/undo-working-copy-modifications-of-one-file-in-git)
- [ответ 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466735/how-to-checkout-only-one-file-from-git-repository-sparse-checkout)
- [git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)